# Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with add friend button

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

So I am trying to figure out how to make an add friend button. I am using Node.JS to route a POST with Jade as my view engine showing an input button in a form that is just an add Contact button. Using Jquery to change the button name from Add Contact to Contact requested on click, and then added the value addContact: Boolean type for my mongoose User Schema.

Here is the node.js app.js file:

```
app.post('/addContact', user.addContactPost);
```

Here is the Node.JS Route file:

```
exports.addContactPost = function(req, res, err) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid,{
                addContact: req.body.addContact
            }, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("post2");
                    return res.render('addContactError', {title: 'Weblio'}); 

                } 

            });
};
```

Here is the Jade file:

```
extends layout
block content   
    div
    legend Search Results
    div#userResults
    for user in ufirstName 
        a(href='/user/#{user.id}')
            p #{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}
        form(method="POST", action="/addContact")
            input(type='submit', id='addContact', value='Add Contact').addContact
```

Here is the Jquery script being called:

```
$('.addContact').click(function() {
    if($(this).value!=='Contact Requested') {
        return $(this).value('Contact Requested');
    }
    });
```

Any Help would be awesome.

Comment: It would be good if you could narrow the focus a little, it's a bit amorphous at the moment and not really a question :) What error are you getting?

Comment: Oh sorry : ), it is actually not POST-ing correctly and adding it to the db.